# Error with Subversion client when using Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, svn

I am using `Intellij IDEA v2021.2` on `Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon` and `Subversion 1.13.0-3`. When I click checkout, I get errors: *"Can't use Subversion command line client svn. The path to the Subversion executable is probably wrong. Fix it."*, *"Cannot load supported formats: Cannot run program "svn" (in directory "/home/alex/intern"): error=2, No such file or directory"*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSyuF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRsjk.png)

Please help those who know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you run `svn` in the shell? If not, is subversion installed? Use `which svn` to find its path and enter that in IntelliJ.

Comment: I found out the path to `svn`: /usr/bin/svn, using the command `which svn` and pasted it into IntelliJ, but the error persisted.

Comment: I found out that when I run the `Intellij IDEA` with super user rights the `Subversion` works.

Comment: You shouldn't run `svn` or an IDE as root. Check the permissions on the svn binary: `ls -l $(which svn)`. It should say something like `-rwxr-xr-x` in the beginning. If it doesn't end in `r-x`, run `sudo chmod 777 $(which svn)` to fix permissions.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I switched to Ubuntu, where it works right away.